# data consistency check : TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: python, typeerror, nonetype

so basically i am writing a some codes to cross check if my data is consistent. 
I have written the below code but it has been showing TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable, i have tried changing the code quite a few times but still the same error comes out. Many thanks.

```
def checkdata(sex,school):
    if (sex == 'F') and ('boys school' in school) :
        return 'inconsistent'
    if (sex == 'M') and ('girls school' in school):
        return 'inconsistent'
    return


def Dif() :
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(DATA_SET,
        [sex, school]) as Cursor :
    for Cols in Cursor :

            Data = checkdata(Cols[0], Cols[1])
            if Data is not None:
                print (Data, " ",Cols)
```

Comment: I suspect that the error message is on the `for` statement (you failed to include the full error message), which means that `Cursor` is `None`, rather than whatever you expected.  Use a `print` statement or two to trace the values you're using.  If you still have trouble, post a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: _Where_ is the error occurring?

btw, I think it's better style to explicitly return `None` at the end of `checkdata()`...

Comment: In fact the full error message was indicating that the error is on these two code : if (sex == 'F') and ('boys school' in school) :
        return 'inconsistent'
    if (sex == 'M') and ('girls school' in school):
        return 'inconsistent'
>>>

Answer (score 0):

In this instance the 'Cursor' variable is None you can check this by printing it before it is used in the loop.

When the loop tries to iterate over None it raises the error shown.

UPDATE:

In that case I would suggest that school is None and the reasoning above holds. Please include the full error message when asking questions like this.

Comment: thank you for your help, but I tried the same loop with other functions and it was fine plus the error message indicating the problem is on those two lines: if (sex == 'F') and ('boys school' in school) : return 'inconsistent' if (sex == 'M') and ('girls school' in school): return 'inconsistent. Just still i cannot find out where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Ah. For one of your data records, you must be getting a `None` as the value of `school`. The `TypeError` is being thrown by the `in` operator, which expects a sequence type as the second operand. `None` isn't a sequence type - it's `None` ;-)

Try adding `print(sex, school)` as the first line of `checkdata()` to confirm the parameters are what you expect.

Comment: thank you. I think this is problem i encountered. Some of the data in school and sex is missing so once it's none, it stops and reveals error. so i have to do right now is to continue running even it is None in the box.